# AEM/ Adobe CQ | Not able to Access DAM asset

Tags: aem

I have a Requirement to Integrate Adobe Aviary img editor with AEM DAM, the problem is when Aviary Tries to access the image from DAM for modification an error occurs stating "Public access on port is required".Does anyone know what changes need to be made in configmgr so aviary can access the DAM on author?

Comment: If you are trying to connect to author instance, then you would need to authenticate yourself before proceeding further. Anonymous access is not allowed in author unless you have specifically enabled it

Comment: aren't there any changes that is required to be made in config files??

Comment: Not unless you want to change some settings within AEM.